# Code release management | SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

I am trying to understand how I can manage my releases of 3 different development track going on without getting in to code merge issue and any functionality loss.

I have already one production release and will going to have 2 parallel development trek for upcoming `release2` and `release3`, however I have following constraints

1. Both `release2` and `release3` will be driven from first release.
2. `Release2` will only going to contain only few features and will have a very short development period.
3. `Release3` will contains some of the new functionalities along with the features developed in `release2`.

I am not very sure how best I can manage these development cycles in SVN so as when we will go live with `release2`, it will be easy for us to merge code in `release3`, also post go live for `release2`, we also need to make sure any bug fix will happen in both production as well the active `release3`.

I am looking for suggestion as what is the best possible way to handle it in more clean way without putting much efforts in code management. As an additional information we are using SVN for code management.

Comment: Is the release1 code on the trunk?

Answer (score 1):

Brad Appleton has a [very thorough analysis](http://www.bradapp.com/acme/branching/) of various branching patterns. While it's almost 20 years old it is still very relevant.
In my work, we are always in the same position as you are facing, and we eventually chose to follow the '[codeline for major release](http://www.bradapp.com/acme/branching/branch-creation.html#CodelinePerMajorRelease)' pattern (C3.1), which we've been using successfully for the past 12 years.

Specifically for your case, I suggest branching both release2 and release3 from the same point on the trunk, and do regular merges from release2 branch to release3. Such merges need to be coordinated in advanced, based on timeline - e.g. every 3 weeks - or according to project milestones, etc.